# Dúvidas com o comando Clear

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Boa noite pessoal.
Sou novo aqui no fórum, então peço desculpas caso já tenham feito esta pergunta.

Minha dúvida é referente ao comando `.clear();` utilizando o selenium webdriver no eclipse.

Bom, estou automatizando um teste em um formulário, e antes de usar o comando sendkeys, estou utilizando o clear. O problema acontece quando executo normal, o comando clear é ignorado e o sendkeys adiciona informação no campo. Mas, quando rodo em modo Debug, o código funciona normalmente.

Já tentei usar `WaitForElementClickable`, e `Thread.Sleep(3000)` mas não adiantou.

```
public void preencherSolicitacao(String UF, String resultado, Boolean positivo) throws InterruptedException {
        SolicitacaoAssistenciaDto solicitacao = form.solicitacaoAssistenciaForm();

        if (positivo) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            inputName.clear();
            inputName.sendKeys(solicitacao.getName());

            Thread.sleep(1200);
            adrress.clear();
            Thread.sleep(1200);
            adrress.sendKeys(solicitacao.getEndereco());
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.
Pelo que pesquisei em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249583/selenium-webdriver-i-want-to-overwrite-value-in-field-instead-of-appending-to-i
e em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799794/how-to-delete-default-values-in-text-field-using-selenium/29173649,

Recomendaram pressionar as teclas Ctrl+A para selecionar o texto antes de definir um novo valor. `element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55");`.

Uma resposta também sugeriu pressionar a tecla HOME para o cursor ir para o início do texto, depois pressionar Shift+Enter para selecionar todo o texto: `element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME, Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.END), "55");`.

*Nunca trabalhei com selenium webdriver mas espero ter ajudado.*

Aguardo sua resposta.